# Docusign Gen for Salesforce error on custom object template button

Tags: document-automation, salesforce

I've created a DocuSign Gen template based on a Salesforce custom object and the preview works well. However, when I try to create the custom action (Lightning button), I get the error "Failed to generate lightning component: Cannot create a new component with the namespace: [custom object]. Only components in the same namespace as the organization can be created through the API".

I tried adding a Remote Site and CSP Trusted Site in Salesforce with our domain name and "--dsgen.na82.visual.force.com", but still getting the same error. Does anyone have a fix for this?